# Bash script to check if a public HTTPS site is up

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to setup another block of code to a bash script to check if a public website on HTTPS is up or not. Can we do this using CURL? Any suggestions what can be used besides CURL. Thanks

Comment: https://www.pingdom.com/

Comment: As Clippy might say, "It looks like you're trying to write a network monitoring system..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using wget instead of curl. Keep in mind that MacOS doesn't come with wget by default.

A successful web request will return a code of 200, a failure will return a 300, 400, 404, ect... (see [REST API codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html))

This line will return a `1` if the web request was successful, otherwise it will return `0`

```
wget -q  -O /tmp/foo google.com | grep '200' /tmp/foo | wc -l
1
```

Comment: I'm aware of the multitude of applications out there to monitor websites but I wanted something simple to be included in my script. The wget -q option works great. Thank you.

Comment: `HEAD google.com | grep '200\ OK' | wc -l` avoids the temp file.

Comment: You can just use `wget` without the temp file: `wget --spider --server-response google.com 2>&1 | grep '200\ OK' | wc -l `. `--server-response` prints the headers, `--spider` prevents downloading the page itself.

Comment: wget is faster then HEAD in this case.

Answer (score 19):

One of many:

```
if curl -s --head  --request GET https://example.com | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
   echo "mysite.com is UP"
else
   echo "mysite.com is DOWN"
fi
```

Comment: As of 2022 you will most likely have to use `grep "HTTP\/2\ 200"` since most servers will have switched to HTTP2 protocol

Answer (score 3):

Nagios' [check_http plugin](https://www.nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html) can do this and much more, including checking for specific text in the response. You can run it from a shell script independently of Nagios itself:

```
$ check_http --ssl -H www.google.com -r 'Feeling Lucky'
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 11900 bytes in 0.086 second response time |time=0.085943s;;;0.000000 size=11900B;;;0

$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: This plugin doesn't have source, you should properly link this. The code is not known.

Comment: This has been an official Nagios plugin since at least 2002, according to the git logs: https://github.com/nagios-plugins/nagios-plugins. It isn't exactly obscure.

Comment: Do you mean this script can be used independently or are you suggesting to install this nagious thing just to solve the bash problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a full solution for monitoring?
I've found monit to be pretty good for this: http://mmonit.com/monit/

(this comes after years of using home brewed bash scripts - i've found monit to be more transportable to different boxes, and more robust than some messy scripts. Don't know about their paid version).

Answer (score 1):

a similiar question was answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747929/linux-script-with-curl-to-check-webservice-is-up

The Qoute is from Burhan Khalid

> curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null
>
> -s = Silent cURL's output
>
> -L = Follow redirects
>
> -w = Custom output format
>
> -o = Redirects the HTML output to /dev/null
>
> Example:
>
> [~]$ curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null
>
> I would probably remove the \n if It were to capture the output.

so you just need to add -k in the options if you do not want to check for a valid certificate and use https instead of http obviously.

```
curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\n" "https://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null
```

reports the status code 200 with a return code of 0.

For everything else you need to define your response in the script.

Comment: I don't think this works for https sites. For http yes, i get a exit status 0

Comment: tested again.
curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\n" "https://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null;echo $?
worked exactly at it should. you get the http code 200, and you get exit 0.

changed formatting, there was at least on linebreak not transfered.

Comment: It does work for google after the command was corrected. Thanks. However, it doesn't for our https site giving an output of 000. I'm using wget now